# Hex-Rays can't parse switch (bad target for case)

Tags: ida, x86

I need to add new case, so here is that I do.

1. Copy the jump table for switch statement to `0048199C` and add new ref to `4819C0`.
   [image]
2. Add new instructions below [image]
3. Set new address `0048199C`[image]
4. In the indirect table for switch statement (`004061C4`) change the one 7 to 8 [image]
5. Apply patches and try using a new case and see how that works. It's ok. The program does what I want.

After that click F5 and finally got such error:
[image]

What's wrong and how do I fix it? I'm using IDA v7.0.170914

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

```
Edit - Other - Specify switch idiom...
```

Set new value for Number of elements: 9

[image]